# different behavior of array v.s. list<T> in Java for sub-class

Tags: java, arrays, list, inheritance

Learned `List<Dog>` is not a sub-class of `List<Animal>` for a number of reasons ([Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p) and [create a list of list of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798434/create-a-list-of-list-of-strings-in-java))

But I tested it seems array works -- an instance of `Dogs[]` could be assigned to an instance of `Animal[]`. But doesn't array has the same issue of put an instance of `Cat` into `Dog` array?

See my below code for `TestArray` which works for array, but `TestList` does not work for `List<T>`.

Any thoughts?

**Source code in Java**,

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestInheritance {

    void TestArray() {
        Dog[] dogs = new Dog[3];
        Animal[] ans = dogs;
        Cat c = new Cat();
        ans[2] = c;
    }

    void TestList() {
        List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
        /*
         * compile error in below statement, Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<TestInheritance.Dog>
         * to List<TestInheritance.Animal>
         */
        List<Animal> ans = dogs;
    }

    class Animal {
        Animal() {

        }

        void WhoAmI() {
            System.out.println("I am Animal!");
        }
    }

    class Dog extends Animal {
        Dog() {

        }

        void Dog() {
            System.out.println("I am Dog!");
        }
    }

    class Cat extends Animal {
        Cat() {

        }

        void Cat() {
            System.out.println("I am Cat!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Arrays are covariant, lists aren't. Array != List.

Comment: try `List<? extends Animal> ans = dogs;`

Comment: An array will throw an `ArrayStoreException` for that issue at runtime, a `List` won't.